# Separate several columns of data that contain hyphens , removing elements in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to separate strings within Python.

Data

```
 Type                 Id        
 aa - generation      aa - generation01 
 aa_led - generation  aa_led - generation01
 ss - generation      ss- generation01
```

Desired

```
Type    Id
aa      aa01
aa_led  aa_led01
ss      ss01
```

Doing

I am trying to incorporate this code into my script, however, this splits by hyphen but my column
names are not reserved.

```
new = wordstring.strip('-').split('-')
```

Any suggestion is appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove `generation` from every value in df. You can use `applymap`:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x : x.replace('- generation', '').replace(' ',''))
```

OUTPUT:

```
     Type        Id        
0      aa       aa01
1  aa_led   aa_led01
2      ss       ss01
```

Comment: Hello thank you - it is giving an error as: 
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: I am researching this